# querying a linked PostgreSQL database in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, postgresql

We will be deploying an application with a Postgres back-end and need to provide report writing capabilities in SQL Server.  I am exploring options for real-time or near real-time reporting in this environment.

I am curious about linking the Postgres database to our SQL Server environment.  Would I be able to build views against the Postgres database that our SQL Server report writers could then use?  Are there any additional performance considerations beyond the normal ones?  (i.e. views are slower than tables)

Comment: Honestly, we just use our linked servers as sources to pull data into our reporting environment. So we have a nightly job that runs something akin to my answer [here](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15817/migrating-tables-from-postgres-to-sql-server-2008/15833) and end users report from the Sql Server itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are OK with the reports being run directly off of the Progress database, look into SQL Server Reporting Services and the Report Builder 2.0 in SQL Server 2008 R2.  If you can deploy Reporting Services 2012 (part of SQL Server 2012) and you've got SharePoint 2010 installed look into using PowerView so allow people to build reports off of data sets which you've pre-defined as part of a data model.

If you need to get the data into SQL Server then you'll probably want to look at building a SQL Server Integration Services package which would then copy the data from the needed tables into the reporting database on a set schedule.